# PIC16F628 PORTA Behaving oddly

Tags: pic

This is a real odd thing I have here.

I picked up a PIC16F628 this morning to play with, and I am having a very strange issue with it.

I have written a very simple program which should light 2 LEDs in this sequence: (* = on, o = off)

```
RA0 RA1
 *   o
 *   *
 o   *
 o   o
```

But what actually happens is:

```
RA0 RA1
 *   o
 o   *
 o   o
 o   o
```

When RA1 turns on, RA0 turns off.

The exact same code run on an '84a works perfectly.  Snippet:

```
loop
    BSF     PORTA,0
    CALL    delay
    BSF     PORTA,1
    CALL    delay
    BCF     PORTA,0
    CALL    delay
    BCF     PORTA,1
    CALL    delay
    GOTO    loop
```

My only thoughts are that it has something to do with the comparators that share the pins (should be disabled by default) which I have tried manually disabling but it has had no effect.

Now, one more thing to add confusion...  If I send absolute values to PORTA (0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00) it works correctly.  Why should the bitwise operations work so strangely?

Oh, and I don't have any issue at all working with PORTB - only PORTA.

Any clues or ideas? Because I have run out.

Comment: How long is "delay"?  1 us?  1 ms?  1 s?

Comment: It's around 0.5 seconds - enough time to see the sequence unfold before me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by the Read-Modify-Write effect, see page 31 of the data sheet. You should use a shadow register, set and reset the bits in that, and write it to the port. Delays usually help, so I find it surprising that it caused you problems. The fact that you could write bytes to the port and it works as expected indicates that it probably is an R-M-W effect.

[Here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/93009A.pdf) is a good description of the problem.

The 18F PICs have latch registers for the ports, and don't suffer from the R-M-W problem.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it is RMW? Because OP mentions that it does not effect PORTB.

Comment: The ports are different, because of the comparator inputs. That might have an effect.

Comment: Well, whatever the reason, abstracting the port via my own register seems to have solved it - seems a bit strange as the data sheet says it does a read-modify-write for all the ports.  My guess is a bug in the system means the read of an output bit is not working right.

Comment: Is it possible that the PORTB has better current capability than PORTA?  RA0 might not rise in time to look like a 1 by the time BSF PORTA,1 is executed.

Comment: Leon is correct. The bit manipulation instructions should never be used with the PORT registers on PICs (even the more modern ones). The bit manipulation instructions read the *entire* 8 bits, modify the desired bit and then write the *entire* 8 bits back again. If you have a 1 output on a pin, but there is a high load on it (relay, LED etc) the voltage on the pin may read back as a '0' although it is set to 1. Thus, it gets written back as a 0 as a result of the RMW process. It is recommended to prepare the value to output in RAM (using BCF/BSF) and then copy it whole to the PORT register.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this question.  The 16F628 defaults on power-up to disabling the digital read circuitry for PORTA.  You need to set the comparator configuration register (CMCON I think) to enable any pins you want to read via the PORTA register (bearing in mind that using bsf/bcf on a port without disturbing the other pins requires being able to read those other pins).